# Call to REST api returns FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I am making my first, simple android app. For the logging in I'm trying to make a request call to a simple API on a webserver:

```
URL url = new URL(API);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Whenever I try to run this, the following comes back:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.gildeict.nl/api/gateway1.0.php at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
```

I also have the following in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The weird thing is that the file does exist. I'm not a pro in java though, so it could be that I'm missing something obvious.

How can it be that something so simple isn't functional?

Thanks.

Comment: have you add INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You cannot get that message back as it is for a statement that you did not post. Read the message to know which code line it was! You should have posted more code. Just post complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be OK. The reason for your error is that the server returns error HTTP code for your request.

For instance, when I try to execute your request with cURL:

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" "http://www.gildeict.nl/api/gateway1.0.php"
```

I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 08:16:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
```

Comment: Could that be any different if you were to post a json string to the api? (I have no idea)

Comment: @WesleyPeeters that could be different, yes. In the end it depends on how server will handle your request and what type of input it expects.